# dynamic name of the style for wp_enqueue_style

Tags: plugins, functions, wp-enqueue-style

I want to use a variable inside the function wp_enqueue_style(), right now the only way i figure out to do so is to define a constant but it needs to be variable

```
 define( 'NAME', 'mystyle' );
 wp_enqueue_style(NAME .'-style', ABS_URL . /includes/box.css' , false );
```

How could I add that variable to this function ? I tried this and it doesnt work, any insights on this?

```
 $name="mystyle";
 wp_enqueue_style($name .'-style', ABS_URL . /includes/box.css' , false );
```

Comment: In what way did it not work?

Comment: the variable $name is empty, it calls the box.css style but the id is "-style-css" instead of "mystyle-style-css"

Comment: Is that the actual code? I can’t see any reason it wouldn’t work.

Comment: How could `$name` be empty if you set it with `$name="mystyle"` just in the previous line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this syntax doesn't seem right to me.

First of all what is `ABS_URL`? If it's a constant that you've defined earlier, then there is an `'` missing before `/includes/box.css'`. The code should look like this:

```
$name = 'mystyle';
wp_enqueue_style( $name .'-style', ABS_URL . '/includes/box.css', false );
```

It works as it should, the output is: `<link rel='stylesheet' id='mystyle-style-css'  href='whatever-there-is-in-ABS_URL-constant' type='text/css' media='all' />`

Also, make sure if you need to define this constant at all - if you want to load stylesheet from your theme's folder or its subfolders, use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` function:

```
$name = 'mystyle';
wp_enqueue_style( $name .'-style', esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . '/includes/box.css' , false );
```

Comment: yeah, it was something really dumb, i didnt pass that variabe as an argument because the wp_enqueue_style was inside a function